# HiveSQL IF ELSE STATMENT Conditions Migration From GreenPlum

Tags: hive, hiveql, greenplum

We have to migrate similar IF ELSE statement from Greenplum to HiveSQL, please help us below statement.

```
SELECT (date_trunc('month', Z_ops_date::date) - interval '1 month')::date into v_lmtd_FrDate;
    SELECT DATE_PART('days' , DATE_TRUNC('month', Z_ops_date::date) - '0 MONTH'::INTERVAL - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL ) INTO v_lmtd_endday;
    SELECT DATE_PART('days', Z_ops_date::date + 1) INTO v_cur_day;
    
    if v_cur_day = 1 then 
        SELECT (DATE_TRUNC('month', Z_ops_date::date) - '0 MONTH'::INTERVAL - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL)::date INTO v_lmtd_ToDate ; -- last day of LMTD
    else
        if v_lmtd_endday > v_cur_day then
            SELECT Z_ops_date::date - substring((select (date_trunc('month',Z_ops_date::date))::date - 1)::character varying,9,10)::integer INTO v_lmtd_ToDate ; -- current day of LMTD
        elseif v_lmtd_endday < v_cur_day then
            SELECT (DATE_TRUNC('month', Z_ops_date::date) - '0 MONTH'::INTERVAL - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL)::date INTO v_lmtd_ToDate ;-- last day of LMTD  
        else 
            SELECT Z_ops_date::date - substring((select (date_trunc('month',Z_ops_date::date))::date - 1)::character varying,9,10)::integer INTO v_lmtd_ToDate ; -- current day of LMTD
        end if;
    end if;
```

above that condition will be applied as below query.

```
SELECT Z_ops_date ,extract(year from Z_ops_date) as Year,extract(month from Z_ops_date) as Month ,service_ID,service_type ,sum(fee_amt_day) as fee_amt_day
    ,v_lmtd_FrDate , v_lmtd_ToDate
    FROM test.sampletable
    WHERE data_date BETWEEN v_lmtd_FrDate AND v_lmtd_ToDate 
    GROUP BY service_ID,service_type ;
```

Comment: `case when` ? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp -- oh i get it,  case when is not what you need. case when accepts columns not queries or tables. Unfortunately, this isn't straight forward in HiveQL. AFAIK, hive can have saved variables but not sure about using a condition on them outside a query

Comment: its possible in hive using subquery but i will not be able to give you exact SQL and i can guide you how to do this whole thing in SQL. let me know if you are interested pls? And also, like your previous questions, please make sure above question has correct problem statement.

Comment: @KoushikRoy - please guide me and this question is correct, i will not change or edit.

Comment: i have find the solution but inner sub query not supporting, please help us